# How to bind combo box with dataset in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I want to bind the combo with dataset and take the value from combo as parameter to populate
another combo in WPF

Comment: That's nice. What's your question?

Comment: Too vague. If you want people to put effort into answers, you will need to put effort into the question. Need more details; a code snippet wouldn't hurt, either.

Answer (score 4):

This should get you started. The `Window_Loaded` event sets up a DataTable with a couple of rows, and sets the `DataContext` and `DisplayMemberPath` of a `ComboBox`. The `Countries_SelectionChanged` event grabs the `SelectedItem` (if there is any) and resets the `Cities.ItemsSource` property to be the result of a method call, which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. This call can be whatever you want (database call, file operation, etc.). Hope this helps!

```
<UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="2">
    <Label Content="Countries" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox Name="Countries" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="Countries_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <Label Content="Cities" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox Name="Cities" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</UniformGrid>   

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));

    DataRow firstRow = dt.NewRow();
    DataRow secondRow = dt.NewRow();
    firstRow["Country"] = "USA";
    secondRow["Country"] = "Italy";
    dt.Rows.Add(firstRow);
    dt.Rows.Add(secondRow);

    Countries.DisplayMemberPath = "Country";
    Countries.DataContext = dt;
}

private void Countries_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    DataRowView dr = Countries.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if (dr != null) {
        Cities.ItemsSource = null;
        Cities.ItemsSource = GetCities(dr["Country"].ToString());
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetCities(string country) {
    if (country == "USA")
        return new []{ "New York", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Dallas", "Denver" };
    if (country == "Italy")
        return new[] { "Rome", "Venice", "Florence", "Pompeii", "Naples" };
    return new[] { "" };
}
```